# How can I add a vanity URL for admin-ajax.php Calls?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

## Background

I'm using the admin-ajax tool in WordPress to build a file generator. I have everything working, except that the current URL is ugly. I'd like to add a vanity URL that looks cleaner.

## My Code

I am already using one vanity URL structure which works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*) /?pagename=products/details&SKU=$2 [QSA,L]
```

However, this new one is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/datasheet-generator/([^/]*) /www/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=fdm_generate_datasheet&SKU=$2 [QSA,L]
```

## Question

Why would this not be working?

Comment: Users should never see the admin-ajax.php URL. It’s only supposed to be used for background AJAX requests. Are you linking users directly to it?

Comment: I'm going to link people directly, which is why I don't want them to see it.